# Suggestions for syncing shared Dropbox folder to local folder

Tags: macos, dropbox

First question here so let me know if it does not belong here.

I use Dropbox for sharing files with collaborators on some projects. When working on the project, I prefer to do it in a local folder. When I have finished some task, I copy the updated version of the file to the shared Dropbox folder on my computer. I have the Dropbox app on my computer, so I am copying between folders on my computer and not uploading via a browser.

Problems arise when someone else updates the file without me noticing (yes, I know there are Dropbox notifications but I don't always notice) and we end up with two parallel versions of the same file that need to be merged.

Does anyone have any simple solution to this problem? I would guess that someone else has encountered the same problem. For example, how can I automatically sync any updates from the shared Dropbox folder to my local folder.

I know git is probably better for this reason, but it is not possible in this case.

I am using macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are manually uploading your files to the *DropBox* cloud file provider.

The easiest solution to this problem is to use an automatic synchronizer. At [the first glance](https://www.dropbox.com/install), apparently *DropBox* may be installed only [on the *MicroSoft* *Windows* operating system](https://www.dropbox.com/download?os=win).

Maybe you can switch to a cloud file provider that is available on the *MacOS* operating system. Try the *Google Drive* cloud file provider. [This one](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) appears to be available for the *Macintosh* machines, also.

It also depends what kind of files you are using. You could write the same documents at the same time with your colleagues on the [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/) web-site. It allows synchronous writing of the same documents.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I am using the dropbox app on my computer. So I am just copying between folders on my computer, not uploading via a browser.

Comment: The file types vary: TeX, pdf, python scripts, data files, etc.

Comment: So you _are_ using the Synchronization Software Utility of the _DropBox_ Cloud File Provider. So it exists _also_ on the _MacOS_ Operating System. I do not see an easy solution for your issue. Even the _Git_ System is not meant for providing Synchronous Access to _Binary_ Files. It is meant for Source Code Control of _Textual_ Files.